# What's wrong with this JSON file please?

Tags: json, atom-editor

[.atom-live-server.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEdVW.png)

What's wrong with this code please ? I cannot find the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A JSON file can only have one root element. There you have two objects:

- one from line 1 to 11,
- another one from 13 to 15

Either separate them in two distinct files or create an object that contains both.